# Google Analytics integration with ASP MVC 5 and AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a project to get website statistics from Google Analytics API using ASP MVC 5 (C#) and AngularJS. I'm not sure how to get started with it. Please guide me to start with this project. What are the things I need to use? (API keys, etc).

I already have a Google account with Google Analytics statistics. I will be developing it using ASP MVC 5 (C#) and AngularJS.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? google analytics gives you a snippet of code to put in the page. Is this not enough? Why not? What else is required? What is the significance of MVC to your question? What is the significance of Angular. It's a very vague question.

Comment: Follow the instructions on the Google Analytics website

Comment: @NewDev i haven't try yet. I'm not sure how to get started with it. i need the steps to start this using ASP MVC 5 (C#) and AngularJS

Comment: @Thasneen, SO is simply not a tutorial site - it's just not suited for it. There is plenty of resources online

Comment: @NewDev, i have searched online but unable to found any resources(for Google Analytics integration using ASP MVC 5 and AngularJS), if you can please provide me some links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two tasks.

1. First set up analytics tracking by integrating google's analytics code snippet in to the web site. Look up [analytics academy](https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/explorer) on this.
2. You will need to access google analytics api. Look at the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).
3. Here is a [code sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html) on using google analytics api to authenticate.
4. Finally you can look at these additional [code samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/tree/master/samples/analytics/v3) on accessing the google analytics API using pure JavaScript.There is no specific methods in angular or MVC5 for accessing the google analytic API.